# ModuleNotFoundError thrown by using pytest in virtualenv in python 3.10

Tags: pytest, virtualenv, python-3.9, python-3.10, modulenotfounderror

I am new to pytest and tried to write a first test case. Since I am new to programming overall, I developed without a virtual environment (naughty, naughty) using the globally installed python version 3.9.13.

The structure of my program is like this:

```
mypkg/
   sub_mypkg/
      file_a.py
      pytest.ini
      testing/
         __init__.py
         test_a.py
```

in which `file_a.py` imports pandas among other modules. The tests in `test_a.py` try among other things to run `file_a.py`.`pytest.ini` adds the root_dir to the PYTHONPATH.

In this setup pytest ran smoothly without any errors.

I then installed a virtualenv using python 3.11 in this project and installed all necessary modules (including pytest) in it and uninstalled pytest globally. After activating the virtualenv and running pytest from the terminal a ModuleNotFoundError was thrown for pandas.

---

Here is a list of the modules I use in venv:

```
Package         Version
--------------- -------
attrs           22.1.0
colorama        0.4.6
contourpy       1.0.6
cycler          0.11.0
et-xmlfile      1.1.0
exceptiongroup  1.0.4
fonttools       4.38.0
iniconfig       1.1.1
kiwisolver      1.4.4
matplotlib      3.6.2
numpy           1.23.4
openpyxl        3.0.10
packaging       21.3
pandas          1.5.1
Pillow          9.3.0
pip             22.3.1
pluggy          1.0.0
pyparsing       3.0.9
pytest          7.2.0
python-dateutil 2.8.2
pytz            2022.6
PyYAML          6.0
setuptools      56.0.0
six             1.16.0
tomli           2.0.1
```

---

I checked that pandas was installed and I could import pandas in the REPL.

Also I could run the test line by line in the REPL.

Furthermore, I checked that the problem was not pandas itself. If I changed the placement of the `import pandas` with for example `import numpy` in `file_a.py`, it threw the ModuleNotFoundError for numpy.

I tried to use different versions of python in my venv (python 3.11.0, 3.10.7, 3.9.13, 3.9.6). Interestingly, pytest ran only inside the venv for python 3.9.13 (The one I developed it in).

I tried to include and delete `__init__.py` files in all directories and also tried different versions of pytest (6.2.5, 7.0.0).

I checked `sys.path` that the right root_dir was included.

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: Can you try to run pytest from your venv directly? Like run your python binary (python for linux or python.exe) from your venv directory. something like: `venv_path/Script/python.exe -m pytest %path_to_test_file%`. Is it working that way?

Comment: @pl3b Unfortunately, that throws the same error.

Comment: Do `venv_path/Script/python.exe -m pip list` contains `pytest`?

Comment: @pl3b: 
Yes, it contains the version 7.2.0